# PHP Design Pattern for Varying ways of Uploading Files

Tags: php, design-patterns, laravel-4

I need to save files uploaded by the user, at the moment I'm just saving them locally, but at some point it's probably going to be changed to store in the cloud, e.g using AWS.

I'm looking for a design pattern that would help me write something which is extensible.

The problems I see are each method of uploading needs different parameters setting, I also need a way to get back the URL the file has been uploaded to, and also I wouldn't want to completely swap out local files to cloud so there needs to be a way for any method to know which upload object it should be using.

I'm using Laravel 4 so if there's any help specific to that it would be useful.

edit..

From the answers so far, I think I can use [Gaufrette](https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette) with an extra layer. I could have a FileUploadManager class to handle all the file upload in the application so everything is in one place.

Each method in that class uses whichever instance of Gaufrette it needs by calling a factory which sets up the adapter with the necessary options:

```
class FileUploadManager {

   protected $fileSystemFactory;

    public __construct(FileSystemFactoryInterface $fileSystemFactory)
    {
        $this->fileSystemFactory = $fileSystemFactory;
    }

    public function uploadUserLogo($filename, $content)
    {
        $filesystem = $this->fileSystemFactory->make('local',array('localdirectory' => 'var/www/public/logos');
        $filesystem->write($filename, $content);
    }

    public function uploadUserCV($filename, $content)
    {
        $filesystem = $this->fileSystemFactory->make('aws',array('aws_bucket' => 'cvs'));
        $filesystem->write($filename, $content);
    }

}


class GaufretteFileSystemFactory implements FileSystemFactoryInterface {

    use Gaufrette\Filesystem;

    public function make($type,$options)
    {
        switch ($type) {
            case 'local':
                $adapter = new LocalAdapter($options['localdirectory'], true);
                return new Filesystem($adapter);
                break;

            case 'aws':
                $adapter = new AmazonS3Adapter($options['aws_bucket']);
                return new Filesystem($adapter);
                break;

        }
    }


}
```

Not sure if this is a good way, and I don't know how I should be handling location of the uploaded resource, should the FileUploadManager care about how the file can be externally accessed?

Comment: Adapter pattern comes to mind for choosing the final destination of a file... local fs, network location, cdn, etc.

Comment: JakeGould - not at all, that's why I specifically asked for a design pattern. Thanks Mike B will look into Adapter pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You need an abstraction layer like [Gaufrette](https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette), which supports all kind of storage layers [local filesystem, AWS...).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the Strategy Pattern?
here's a template to get you started;

```
<?php
   abstract class FileUploader{
      public function uploadFile(){

         //insert the code to acquire the current temporary file path here
         return $this->moveFile($temporaryFilePath);
      }

      abstract function moveFile($tempFile);
   }

   class LocalFileUploader extends FileUploader{
      function moveFile($tempFile){
         //put the rest of the code you have to move the file to the local directory
         return $success ? $success : $error; //return the value you are currently returning from here
      }
   }

   class RemoteFileUploader extends FileUploader{
      function moveFile($tempFile){
         //put the code here that you will use to upload the file to the remote server
         return $success ? $success : $error; //return a success or error from here
      }
   }
?>
```

what do you think? this and the chain of command patterns are the ones I use the most when it comes to specialization of a common function